# Why does the Reader monad store a function?

Tags: haskell, monads

According to
[All about monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Reader_monad)

> Monad values (of the Reader monad) are functions from the environment to a value. The bound
>   function is applied to the bound value, and both have access to the
>   shared environment.

But, why is it necessary to use a function (and not, for instance, two variables, one for the environment and one for the value) in this monad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The point of the reader monad is to model a value which *depends* on some environment. Or, if you prefer, a computation with an "implicit" input. This is different from a value which is stored along its environment.

Consider this:

```
newtype Reader s a = Reader (s -> a)

ask :: Reader a a
ask = Reader (\s -> s)
```

here the value and the environment are the same. The above simply "gets" the value from the environment and returns it.

By contrast,

```
newtype Reader s a = Reader (s, a)

ask :: Reader a a
ask = Reader (s, s)
   where s = ???
```

here we need to produce both the environment and the value. But we have no actual way to do that! The environment moved from being an input, in the first example, to being an output -- and this makes realizing `ask` impossible.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat more mathematical argument:

Consider what happens when you *modify* the environment. For instance, say you have an environment with an `Int` in in, but your `Reader` requires an `Integer`. I.e., you have

```
yourReader :: Reader Integer A
```

Well, clearly you can convert the `Int` in the environment, just use

```
fromIntegral :: Int -> Integer
```

But what this means for your reader monad is that you *[convert](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:withReader) to `Reader Int A`*, because only that type works in your original environment.

```
yourReader' :: Reader Int A
yourReader' = withReader fromIntegral yourReader
```

Mathematicians describe this by saying `Reader` is [**contra**variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance) in its first argument. But if it consisted of just a variable for the value and one for the environment, then it would be **co**variant in both arguments (i.e. `Int -> Integer` would transform `Reader Int A` to `Reader Integer A`, not the other way around). Whereas a function type is contravariant in its left side.